# scipy.optimize.minimize() standard function error in example?

Tags: python, scipy

I will shortly explain what happened. I was learning ([scipy.optimize tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#kk)) example (`Nelder-Mead Simplex algorithm`) to understand the minimize function, but error occures as shown below.
How can I fix it? I did not add any new values I just copied sample values and example.

```
from scipy import optimize

def rosen(x):
     return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0) + (1 - x[:-1])**2.0)

x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
res = optimize.minimize(rosen, x0, method='nelder-mead',
            options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})


Command line: C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\Desktop\FSFDSD~1.PY
Working directory: C:\Users\Desktop
Timeout: 0 ms

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\FSFDSD~1.PY", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\FSFDSD~1.PY", line 40, in main
    options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 338, in minimize
    return _minimize_neldermead(fun, x0, args, callback, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 424, in 
 _minimize_neldermead
    fsim[0] = func(x0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 268, in function_wrapper
    return function(x, args)
TypeError: rosen() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Process "Python Interpreter" terminated, ExitCode: 00000001
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce this error with `scipy 0.13.0` and `python 2.7.5`.  The code runs without error, but the minimization doesn't work: `res['success']` is `False`.

Comment: @askewchan - I reinstalled my scipy (by taking 0.13.0 version), and it worked.. I dunno why I had that mistake... also `res['success'] is False` in my IDLE

Comment: There's a typo in your function. In the tutorial the code is
    ```def rosen(x):
           """The Rosenbrock function"""
           return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)```